# Unable to apply jquery multiselect widget with ajax populated values

Tags: jquery, struts

I am using ajax to fill in my select dropdown. I am using this [widget](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/) to beautify my multiselect dropdown. But for some reason, the dropdown is not getting populated after using this widget. Here is my code. The app is using struts

```
<html:select styleId="code" name="Form" property="selCode" multiple="multiple"> 
 <logic:iterate id="clist" name="Form" property="CodeList">
  <option value=<bean:write name="cclist" property="id"/>>
  <bean:write name="cclist" property="value"/></option>
 </logic:iterate> 
</html:select>

$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#code").multiselect().multiselectfilter();;
});
```

Comment: I read the documentation real fast, said you should call refresh when you load in ajax values, I don't see your ajax clal, but in the `success:function(){` part, just do `$('#chargecode').multiselect('refresh');` it looks like

Comment: Where did you set id="chargecode"? I don't know how struts works, but seems that you are not setting it anywhere, so $("#chargecode") does not get an element to apply multiselect.

Comment: Thanks Ohgodwhy. You are a star! +1 for you